# Issue while injecting repository in @TestComponent class when running @DataJpaTest tests

Tags: kotlin, testing, repository, spring-boot-test

I struggle writing some repository tests for a Spring Boot REST service (written in Kotlin).
While repository injection (using `@Autowired`) works perfectly in `OrderServiceTests` class (which is the tests class).
Same injection fails in `TestDatabaseCreator` class (which is a `@TestComponent` annotated class). (It also fails with `@Component` annotation)

=> It looks like @Component and @TestComponent do not access the test context.
=> I must miss something obvious

If someone can help, that would be great !

Here is the code sample:

```
@DataJpaTest
class OrderServiceTests {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var orderRepository: OrderRepository
    private lateinit var testSet: TestDatabaseCreator

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        testSet = TestDatabaseCreator()
    }

    @Test
    fun `Add a consistent new order`() {
        orderRepository.findAll()           // Works perfectly
        testSet.populateTestSet()
}

@TestComponent
class TestDatabaseCreator {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var orderRepository: OrderRepository

    fun populateTestSet() {
        orderRepository.findAll()           // Fails with userRepository not initialized
    }
}
```

and the error message:

```
lateinit property orderRepository has not been initialized
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property orderRepository has not been initialized
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a self-managed `TestDatabaseCreator` which has an `@Autowired` `OrderRepository`. This will not work as Spring will not be processing the `@Autowired` annotation on the `OrderRepository` inside of `TestDatabaseCreator`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer !
May I ask why `@Autowired` annotation won't be processed by Spring ?
Any idea for a workaround ?